# Отмена подписки на бота python

Tags: python, telebot

```
import telebot, bs4, requests

import threading as th

bot = telebot.TeleBot("мой_токен")

keyboard1 = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup()
keyboard1.row('Анекдот')
keyboard1.row('Подписатся на розсылку (каждые 30 мин)')

keyboard2 = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup()
keyboard2.row('Анекдот прямо сейчас!')
keyboard2.row('Отменить подписку')

def getanekdot():
    z=''
    s=requests.get('http://anekdotme.ru/random')
    b=bs4.BeautifulSoup(s.text, "html.parser")
    p=b.select('.anekdot_text')
for x in p:
    s=(x.getText().strip())
    z=z+s+'\n\n'
return s


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
def handle_start_help(message):
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, u'Напишите мне слово Анекдот',reply_markup=keyboard1)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def handle_text(message):
    msg=message.text.lower()
    if (u'анекдот' in msg):
        try:
            bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, getanekdot())
        except:
            pass
    elif (u'подписатся' in msg):
        def interval_timer(timer_stop):
            if not timer_stop.is_set():
                th.Timer(5, interval_timer, [timer_stop]).start()
                try:
                    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, getanekdot(),reply_markup=keyboard2)
                except:
                    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,'Проблемы при загрузки...')
        timer_stop = th.Event()
        interval_timer(timer_stop)

    elif (u'отменить подписку' in msg):
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,'Подписка отменена',reply_markup=keyboard1)

    else:
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, u'Напишите мне слово Анекдот"')

bot.polling()
```

Делаю бота на питоне. Пользователь просит анекдоты , а бот их отправляет(рамдомные). Сделал я подписку на бота , тип он будет отправлять анекдоты сам каждые 5 секунд (это для теста 5 с , а вообще будет каждые 30мин). Теперь хочу сделать ОТПИСКУ от бота , но не пойму как. Мне нужно при вводе "отменить подписку" остановить функцию interval_timer(). Как это сделать , помогите ???!!☹️(если что , это не весь код)

Comment: код текстов в вопрос

Comment: Код добавлен, смотрите